Is running python inside an activated venv similar to using venv\python.exe?
I'm trying to schedule a python script to run in an venv via windows task scheduler.
In a normal command prompt I would have done:
Cd\foldername
Venv\scripts\activate
Python filename.py

However in task scheduler is the following doing the same?
C:\foldername\venv\python.exe filename.py


The only difference I can think of is that when you directly specify python from a venv path like C:\foldername\venv\python.exe the
system's PATH doesn't get modified and you might need to explicitly modify it.

What is the appropriate way to invoke python program in a venv via task scheduler? I don't want to update system's path. I think you are saying that if  I don't do this then it will still use the global python packages even though I call ok python from the venv folder?

I would recommend activating using .bat file. C:\foldername\venv\Scripts\activate.bat and then on the next line running your python script

Any alteration that a virtualenv makes to PATH only affects the current CMD context. The PATH setting that you see in whatever control panel Windows uses nowadays is not the PATH environment variable itself, but rather a template that is used to initialize each new CMD. That said, if you don't need an altered PATH (because of, for example, the Python code caring about that setting), it works perfectly well to just give the path to the venv's Python explicitly, yes. Activation is only a convenience to make the python command work nicely. Creating the venv was the actual magic.

But I'm not writing that as an answer because all this material should be adequately covered by existing Q&A. If the above-linked questions don't have adequate answers, they should be given answers that incorporate that material - because it's in scope for the questions.
